# Nested javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have some objects like this: (wordpress attachment object)

```
attachment.sizes (which is an object and contains:) 
                .full (each contains height and width:)
                     .height
                     .width
                .medium
                       .height
                       .width
                .thumbnail
                          .height
                          .width
```

And then I have another object:

```
props.size (which is either "full","medium" or "thumbnail")
```

Can I in some way write similar to

```
attachment.sizes.(props.size).height
```

To get the height? (That did not work when I tried)

Comment: I think `attachment.sizes[props.size].height` should work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using `[]`:

```
attachment.sizes[props.size].height
```

Both notations, `a.b` and `a['b']`, are equivalent, but only `[]` let you use a variable name as the property.